# Eclipse Organize Imports Shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+O) is not working

Tags: java, python, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, shortcut

Eclipse used to import missing packages when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

The shortcut key has stopped working when used in Java files but the same shortcut is working in Python files (importing missing packages).

Any thoughts on how to fix the issue.

Below are couple of snapshots for your reference.

[image: Keys Binding]

[image: Organize Imports in Source]

Comment: Would probably be helpful if you let us know which version of Eclipse you're using (Kepler,Mars, etc.)

Comment: @Neil I am using Eclipse Neon.3

Comment: Vote +1. I have the same problem, using default key binding on Spring Tool Suite - Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE, Build Id: 201707061903, Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To fix this issue:

Go to `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys`
Click on `Filters...` and de-select `Filter uncategorized commands` then `Ok`.

Then look for the command `Go To Symbol in File` and select it.
Then click on `Unbind` and then `Apply` and Close

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>**. should now work.

EDIT:

Also unbind any other conflicting commands and leave only one command for **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>** and set the `When` to `Editing Java Source`.

Comment: This worked for me on a Mac, whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: Same things on W7 with Eclipse Neon and Spring Tool Suite. Thanks again, made my day.

Answer (score 59):

The Java *Organize Import* command is **overwritten by another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> command**: in *Window > Preferences: General > Keys* the Java *Organize Import* command (where *When* is *In Windows*) is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, but in the main and right-click menu *Source > Organize Imports* the command is displayed without the shortcut.

There are two solutions for this problem:

- Change or **remove the shortcut of the command that overwrites** the Java *Organize Import* command:

  1. Find the command: In the Java editor press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and see which command is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. Probably, it is the ***Beans Quick Outline*** command.
  2. In *Window > Preferences: General > Keys* change or remove the binding for the found command.
- **Restricts the scope of the shortcut** of Java *Organize Import* to the Java editor:

  1. In *Window > Preferences: General > Keys* select the Java ***Organize Import*** command and **change *When*** from ***In Windows*** to ***Editing Java Source***. This solution restricts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to the Java editor and disables the shortcut in the *Package/Project Explorer*.

See also: [Spring IDE issue #160: *organize imports is not working*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/160)

Comment: The link provided has helped to resolve the issue.
By changing the **when** from **In Windows** to **Editing Java Source**, the shortcut key started to work.
Thank you!

Comment: By changing the ***When*** from ***In Windows*** to ***Editing Java Source***, the shortcut will only work in the Java editor and **no longer in the *Package/Project Explorer***. But that may be okay for most users.

Answer (score 22):

Please keep in mind that if you are using an AMD GPU, your Radeon Driver could block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which is used to toggle an ingame-overlay. It can be changed to other keys as follows: **Games → global settings → performance monitoring**

Comment: This solved for my case. Radeon realy blocks your Ctrl+Shift+O. I was already getting nuts on it!

Comment: This is what it was for me, recently updated my radeon drivers and my eclipse bindings stopped working. After 2 hours of trying to figure it out i read this and it all made sense. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! Oh man, I spent hours trying to figure this and it was the Radeon thing!

Comment: Yes. This finally solved my problem after trying all the other solutions. Wish I'd seen this sooner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Click on Binding to sort by Binding then scroll and find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

If several Organized imports are present edit one bind and choose WHEN: EDITING JAVA SOURCE.

Remove( UNBIND COMMAND) for other existing bindings.

Restart Eclipse
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Above shortcut resulted in GPU details being popped up on my screen. SO it was bound to some other app which was overriding it. What worked for me is 
 -> [check](https://community.amd.com/thread/227221).

You need to go to Gaming > Global Settings > Performance Monitoring > Toggle Performance Logging Hotkey

You will see this is bound to Ctrl + Shift + O (so the shortcut is used - just buried).

To remove the shortcut (not an obvious process at all!) you need to click the Toggle Performance Logging Hotkey button, it will then ask to enter your hotkey, you then press delete - that is Del (not backspace, not esc or anything else - the Del key).

Answer (score -1):

i did all but not worked so i checked the AMD forum (https://community.amd.com/thread/227221) and found out my solution which is;
"Now I find that all I need to do is to go to Radeon Settings -> Preferences and uncheck the Show Overlay box."