# Eclipse Organize Imports shortcut not working on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse (STS version 3.9.0) on macOS Sierra.  I have a fresh install of STS.  Organize Imports (Cmd + Shift + O) is defined out of the box.  I can get this function to work by going through the menu entry Source > Organize Imports, but the key combination does nothing.

Additionally, the shortcut combination is not shown next to the menu item, while other menu items do have shortcut combinations shown.
[image: Missing menu shortcut]

What can I do to get this functionality via keystroke?

I have seen this happen on two different machines.

I have checked there are no other conflicting keybindings by sorting by the binding:

[image: Properties | Keys]

Comment: Is it assigned in the 'General > Keys' section of the Preferences?  This works fine for me on macOS with plain Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: @greg-449 yes it is

Comment: Just guessing but you could check for a clash with a macOS shortcut (look in the macOS System Preferences in the Keyboard section on the Shortcuts tab).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Organize Imports Shortcut - Ctrl+Shift+o is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256038/eclipse-organize-imports-shortcut-ctrlshifto-is-not-working)

Comment: @greg-449 yes, I suspected that also.  I checked and no clashes there either

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think this is the same.  Hopefully my edits will show that.

Comment: In _Preferences_, could you filter the keys for `⇧⌘O`?

Comment: @howlger I did that. Please see screenshot.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @PaulWaldo The screenshot does not show the filter field above the table. Was it empty? The Java _Organize Imports_ is set to the widest possible scope _When In Windows_ (because it is not only available in the Java Editor but also in the Package/Project Explorer). It will be overridden by every command bound to the same shortcut but with a more specific scope, e. g.  _Text Editing_ or _Editing in Structured Text Editors_. To which shortcut is your _Beans Quick Outline_ command bound? For details see [my answer for Linux/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266159/6505250).

Comment: @howlger thanks for that suggestion and pointer.  It turns out the comment in your answer by user206079 was the key: "The link provided has helped to resolve the issue. By changing the **when** from **In Windows** to **Editing Java Source**, the shortcut key started to work."  Note that unbinding Beans Quick Outline did not work.  I can now Organize Imports in a Java file.  It seems odd that default key bindings have this broken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Preferences > General > Keys > Filter the keys for ⇧⌘O

By changing the **When** from **In Windows** to **Editing Java Source**, the shortcut key started to work for me.

*I've seen the answer on the comments above but it wasn't easy to see, that's why I'm writing it right here for more clarity. Thanks Paul for the question & answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences-> General -> Keys on STS Menu
2. Click "Filters..." on the Keys page and uncheck all.
3. Enter "⇧+⌘+O" to search the command list for <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
4. You can see the command list, and then unbind commands other than "Organize Imports".
5. Click "Apply".