# Disable hotkey F11 to execute aws servless in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin

I used to use Eclipse hotkey all the time and after to install the AWS plugin the <kbd>F11</kbd> sometimes try to execute regular code or JUnit as servlets.

I try to disable or change the hotkey but I can't find it, someone can help me?

Comment: In _Window > Preference: General > Keys_ enter `F11` in the filter field to see to which commands F11 is bound. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45256038/6505250

Comment: Thanks for the help, I look at and just found some items as: Coverage - Shift+Ctrl+F11, Debug - F11, Graphical Designer - Shift+Ctrl+F11, Run - Ctrl+F11, Toggle Full Screen - Alt+F11, but not aws serverless.

Comment: Did you disable all filters (via _Filters..._ button)? Depending on the view or editor in which the focus is, different keyboard shortcuts are active (Ctrl+Shift+L to get a list). In which editors/views you want to disable F11?

Comment: I tried with enabled and disabled filters, but the Ctrl+Shift+L show me all and I can disable, thanks.